# How can i install my burp certificate in the system credentials of the emulator running on UBUNTU and how to make it a writable system to remount?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, burp

adb remount says failed as i want to make the system writable it is not letting me to do so from the Ubuntu Terminal , Please help to make the android virtual device writable as i have installed the necessary requirements.

TO get the solution